# Terminal, Editor, Project

Tags: j

I want to write a piece of code, a loop. 
So I start:

```
for_i. i.10 do.
```

Press "Enter" in order to write a new line, get an error:

```
|spelling error
|   for_i. i.10 do.
|   ^
```

So I go to the Editor (one with green code area, Terminal has yellow color).
Write these code, press "run". 
But Editor runs code in the Terminal as well. And yes, I get the same error.
I start new project in Editor. Write the code. Press "run project". And??? Nothing. No errors, no results, no anything.
I know that I can wrap this code into function, like

```
f =: 3 : 0
   for_i. i.10 do.
   ....
)
```

And it will work.
But why doesn't it work in straightforward way?
Why doesn't it work even in editor? 
How to make a code in projects run? And where should I see results?

Answer (score 1):

Think of editor as an area of definition. By assigning definitions to variables using =: (necessary because =. only establishes assignment local to the editor) running the editor script establishes those definitions in your terminal, where you can actually run them.

If you actually want to run a verb from the editor, write the verb with its arguments in the editor and then the  verb will be executed and produce results. After all, that is what it is doing with the assignments, but in that case the execution produces the assigned definitions.

Try this in your editor and see if it makes more sense when you run it.

```
a=: 3 : 0    NB. establishes definition of a. This needs to be defined first
+/y
)

a 2 3 4 5  NB. runs a in Terminal from editor
```

Answer (score 1):

J's [control](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/ctrl.htm) structures only work in an explicit definition (which is what bob was getting at).

If you want to use them on a single line, you'll need a complete enclosing explicit definition on that line. And if you want results from that line you will also need to provide that definition with an argument to work on.

For example:

verb def 'for_i. i.10 do. echo i end.' 0